# React Context API: StateProvider not rendering app component

Tags: reactjs

I am using React-Context-API instead of redux, but after creating the StateProvider and reducer, when i wrap the app component inside the StateProvider in Index.js. My whole app is replaced with a white page on the local host. The code snippets are below.

Index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { StateProvider } from "./StateProvider";
import reducer, { initialState } from "./reducer";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

StateProvider.js

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, childern }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {childern}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStatevalue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

reducer.js

```js
export const initialState = {
  //   user: null,
  basket: [],
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
      break;
    case "REMOVE_FROM_BASKET":
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Your state has to be an actual state in the StateProvider component not a Javascript object

Comment: Can you give an example i didn't understand. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`childern` must be `children` in `StateProvider.js`

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `children`. And your reducer should always return the state and not `break`.